# Making a regexp to retrieve href/src of html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Im trying to get the href from links and src from script tags.
Since it's my first time using regex, im isuing quite not enough understand on how groups, negation and conditional selection works.

This is what i've got so far

`(\/|\.\/)((^([http|https]:\/\/))*.*?\w+)([a-zA-Z]\w+)(?=\.(js|css|ts)\b)(.*?\w+)`

Working in this cases:

```html
<script src="./script.js"/>
<script src="/script.js"/>
<script src="/my/custom/dir/script.js"/>
<!--Theme same for links-->
```

Non functioning cases:

```html
<script src="https://my.cdn.fav/script.js"/>
<script src="http://my.cdn.fav/script.js"/>
```

Or well it does consider the starting http and https but doesnt select them.
It's this part that is doing something wrong `(\/|\.\/)((^([http|https]:\/\/))`

Comment: Any reason you don't iterate all `script` tags and get the `src`? What string are you testing in the `RegExp`?

Comment: @guest271314 performance? or is this less performant? you mean by using something like cheerio?
Im testing the string in the script tags

Comment: I don't think `RegExp` is recognized as "performant" cf. iterating DOM nodes. Though you can quickly find out with a test. Are your `<script>` tags really written as `<script src="/script.js"/>`? `<script>` tags are not self-closing the last time I checked.

Comment: RegExes aren't suited to parse nested expressions (HTML, JSON, code, ...). Use a [proper parser instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: Yea thank you so much for answering!Maybe i just wanted and excuse to learn regex with wouldnt be bad and tried to find a hard solution.But since im using bun im just going too use their built in html dom parser https://bun.sh/docs/bundler/macros#make-fetch-requests-at-bundle-time

Answer (score 1):

Given your input string you can replace everything you are not trying to match with something like `.replace(/<script\ssrc="|"\/>/g, " ").split(/[\n\s]+/).filter(Boolean)`

```js
let matches = `<script src="https://my.cdn.fav/script.js"/>
<script src="http://my.cdn.fav/script.js"/><script src="./script.js"/>
<script src="/script.js"/>
<script src="/my/custom/dir/script.js"/>`.replace(/<script\ssrc="|"\/>/g, " ").split(/[\n\s]+/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: `<script type="module" src="//example.net/js/random-script.js"></script>`? I'm not particularly good at regular expressions, but given the `<script\s src...>` I'd imagine that would create a problem. Not to the extent that it's worth down-voting, but even so. Also, if you could explain what this regexp does, for the benefit of those trying to learn from this question and answer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidThomas I used the strings at OP. None of them have closing `</script>`. I explained what is going on in the text of the answer. Remove everything except the expected match `/<script\ssrc="|"\/>/`, split newline and space characters `/[\n\s]+/`, filter empty strings `''` from resulting array.